Explain the expansion of Cooley-Tukey FFT
Can anyone explain the following Cooley-Tukey FFT expansion.
$$V_k = \sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\omega^{ik}v_i$$
Now let $n = n'n''$,
also $i=i'+n'i''$ where $i'=0,\dots,n'-1$,
$i''=0,\dots,n''-1$ and $k=n''k'+k''$ where $k'=0,\dots,n'-1$ and
$k''=0,\dots,n''-1$.
Now rewriting the initial sum
$V_{n''k'+k''} = \sum_{i''=0}^{n''-1}\sum^{n'-1}_{i'=0}\omega^{(i'+n'i'')(n''k'+k'')}v_{i'+n'i''}$
I have hard time understanding the sum decomposition here:
$$
\sum()^{n'n''-1}_{i'+n'i''=0} = \sum()_{i''=0}^{n''-1}\sum()^{n'-1}_{i'=0}
$$
Your help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thank you!

You may have chosen a notation that makes this way more complicated than it needs to be. The whole idea is to break up a single sum over, say 15, elements into either 5 sums of 3 or 3 sums of 5. You can think about it of rearranging a single large index vector into a rectangular matrix.   You can either sum one row at a time or one column at a time,
